# How can i divide two expressions in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql

How can i divide two expressions in Microsoft SQL Server which give Numbers as a Result? I tried with a /, but this didn't work

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE c = 1
```

I tried with  / but this didnt work

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM A/SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE c = 1
```

Comment: One idea: store the counts in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might depend on RDBMS, this works in sql server.

```
SELECT ACounts/ CAST(BCounts AS Decimal(29,20))
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ACounts FROM A) AS suba
, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS BCounts FROM B WHERE c = 1) AS subb
```

Note that I cast the BCounts to a decimal of arbitrary size otherwise it will round off to the nearest whole number. Ignore that part if that is what you wanted.

This also works

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ACounts FROM A)/ CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) AS BCounts FROM B WHERE c = 1) AS Decimal(29,20))
```

Comment: but where is the division? a first line

Comment: but how can i make it abstract since i dont have concrete numbers like 29,20?

Comment: @anna - ?? That is the conversion from `int` to a `decimal`, it states the precision is up to 29 digits with up to 20 of those occurring after the decimal.

Comment: @anna - you can remove that but your division will then always result in a rounded whole number like 0 or 1. None of the above is hard coded, its all based on the query from table `A` and table `B`.

Comment: thnk you, but why i need suba and subb?

Comment: @anna - Maybe this is a better example for you. Copy and paste both of these statements into your query editor and run them to see the difference. `SELECT 13/CAST(557 AS DECIMAL(29,20))` and
`SELECT 13/557`

Comment: @anna - The second example in my answer above is a condensed version without using aliases. They both are equivalent to the same thing.

Comment: how can i make it precise to one number after the comma? for ex, 24.5?

Comment: @anna - change `DECIMAL(29,20)` to `DECIMAL(18,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries:

```
SELECT (a.countA / b.countB) As divisionResult 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS countA FROM A) a,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS countB FROM B WHERE c = 1) b
;
```